# Task Scheduler and BAT script not working properly

Tags: python, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

In my server I have Python running as Standalone, so I have to call the "python.exe" the script "script.py" and the list "1.txt". My syntax looks like this.

```
D:\Script\Python>python.exe script.py 1.txt
```

Now, I want to automate it as a Daily task at 11:00 and I created a .BAT which looks like this.

```
"D:\Script\Python\python.exe" "D:\Script\Python\script.py" "D:\Script\Python\1.txt"
```

The script script.py is generating automatically a .CSV file in the same folder which is very important. If I run the script by CMD the CSV is generated properly, If I run the script by the .BAT file also its generated properly.

But when Task Scheduler is accesing the same .BAT file, there is no .CSV generated. Also the script seems to be running fine until the .CSV part.

Can someone explain me why task.BAT is working manually but not automatically?

EDIT: After checking out Task Manager in Details tab with the column "Command Line" enabled, python.exe is ending too fast.

Comment: Make sure when you create a Task in Task Scheduler you select "New task" **Not "Basic task"** - converting later has still seen issues time.  Click the checkbox "`Run with highest privileges`" (This is an elevated `cmd` prompt) make sure yours selecting to `run whether the user is logged in or not` and the user as an administrator in the system (Save the password) and make sure that the `compatibility level` is set to the newest version of windows available in the drop down.  Make sure the user the script runs as has write access to the output diectory.

Comment: @BenPersonick Hello Ben, thank your for your answer, I have done everything what you said and the issue still persists

Comment: 1) Have you logged in with the same user you are running the script as to see if it runs correctly as a batch script?  2)  Does the script run correctly when you are logged in and kick off the task manually?  3) Can you put in output to track the progress of the script in a Log file? and possibly save any errors?

Comment: @BenPersonick I think it might be because I forgot to specify where I want to start the program. Now its generating the CSV, I will come tomorrow with a feedback :)